# build df from sum of column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum, aggregate-functions

I need to group the data by customer_id and get the sum of purchase for each months. My data looks like this:

```
cust_id        months
1               1
1               1
1               2
1               4
2               1
2               1
```

So I need to see the sum of purchase for each months and each customer. The desired output is:

```
cust_id     mo1     mo2     mo3     mo4
1           2       1       0       1
1           2       0       0       0
```

Comment: In real data some months are missing?

Comment: @jezrael yes, a cust might not purchase in some months

Comment: And need all months - 1 to `12` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for add missing categories:

```
r = range(df['months'].min(), df['months'].max() + 1)
df = (pd.crosstab(df['cust_id'],df['months'])
        .reindex(r, axis=1, fill_value=0)
        .add_prefix('mo'))
print (df)
months   mo1  mo2  mo3  mo4
cust_id                    
1          2    1    0    1
2          2    0    0    0
```

If need all months is possible use ordered categoricals:

```
df['months'] = pd.Categorical(df['months'], ordered=True, categories=range(1, 13))

df = df.groupby(['cust_id','months']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).add_prefix('mo')
print (df)
months   mo1  mo2  mo3  mo4  mo5  mo6  mo7  mo8  mo9  mo10  mo11  mo12
cust_id                                                               
1          2    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
2          2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
```

Or `reindex` by `range` for all months:

```
r = range(1, 13)
df = (pd.crosstab(df['cust_id'],df['months'])
        .reindex(r, axis=1, fill_value=0)
        .add_prefix('mo'))
print (df)
months   mo1  mo2  mo3  mo4  mo5  mo6  mo7  mo8  mo9  mo10  mo11  mo12
cust_id                                                               
1          2    1    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
2          2    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0     0     0     0
```

Comment: how to change the column to be unstacked?
(there's no 'months' on the 'cust_id')

Comment: @chimmytata - Use `df.rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)`